# Compile error in threaded class

Tags: java, abstract

I have a `class` (below) however whenever I try to compile the code I get an error that says the `class` isn't `abstract`.

Can anyone explain what this means and what I need to do differently?

```
package huntermessenger;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HunterClient implements Runnable {
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 5000;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   //to read text from the console
    Socket socket = null;

    public void Run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting to server: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (out == null) {
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                }

                //read a string
                System.out.println("Enter a message: ");
                String str = scanner.next();

                //send it to server
                out.writeObject(new Message(str));
                out.flush();

                //get the reply from the server
                if (in == null) {
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                }
                Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
                System.out.println("Server said: " + message.getMessage());

            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you miss the `run()` method. Please read the Java Code Conventions.

Comment: Use a decent IDE. It will warn you very early.

Answer (score 4):

java is case sensitive:

```
public void Run() {
```

is not same as

```
public void run() {
```

you need to implement `run()` not `Run()`.

just change it to

```
public void run() {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Run() {}
```

Run() should not be capitalized. run() is an abstract method, and you are not overriding it since you are implementing Run() instead. As such, your class still has an abstract method, but the class is not abstract, hence the error.